# Neumann boundary conditions in NDSolve over nontrivial region

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method

The problem I would like to solve involves diffusion in the following region

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[-5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5 && x^2 + y^2 >= 1^2, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Region over which to solve PDE]

Additionally, there is an interaction potential $v$ acting in this region:

```
v = Function[{x, y}, -E^(-x^2 - y^2)];
Plot3D[v[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > 1^2], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: plot of interaction potential]

Physically, I would like to model 2D diffusion confined to this region, in the presence of the biasing potential given by $v$. So what I need to do is solve the PDE
$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\vec{\nabla}u(x,y) + u(x,y) \vec{\nabla}v(x,y)\right] = 0$
subject to the boundary conditions

$u(x,-5) = 1$

$u(x,5) =0$

to impose an overall flux, and with zero-flux boundary conditions at the boundary where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, (as well as on the sides where $x = \pm 5$).
So I proceed as follows in Mathematica (10.0.0):

```
op = Div[Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y] Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}],{x, y}];
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == -5],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 5]};
```

Note that I did not specify boundary conditions for the circular boundary, nor for the sides $x = \pm 5$, because according to the NDSolve/NeumannValue documentation, these should default to zero-flux boundary conditions.

```
sol = NDSolve[{op == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005}}]
```

The solution looks like this:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Solution of the PDE]

Now, this is not quite what I expected, for the following reason:if the PDE is solved correctly, with zero-flux boundary conditions, then the flux into the box (at y = -5) should equal the flux out of the box (at y = 5). You can sort of tell that this is not the case from the plot above, but plotting the normal derivative at the boundaries $y = \pm 5$ makes it clear:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[(Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 5] + u[x, 5] Derivative[0, 1][v][x, 5]) /.sol],
Evaluate[(Derivative[0, 1][u][x, -5] + u[x, -5] Derivative[0, 1][v][x, -5]) /. sol]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0}]
```

[image: normal derivatives]

Integrating these will give the flux in and the flux out. Clearly the flux in is not equal to the flux out. Since I have checked to make sure that the PDE $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\vec{\nabla}u(x,y) + u(x,y) \vec{\nabla}v(x,y)\right] = 0$ is obeyed in the interior of the region, it seems that I am not correctly setting the Neumann boundary condition at the circular boundary $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. The boundary condition that I *want* is

$\left[\vec{\nabla}u(x,y) + u(x,y) \vec{\nabla}v(x,y)\right] \cdot \vec{n} = 0$

but I *believe* that the boundary condition that I'm *getting* is simply

$\left[\vec{\nabla}u(x,y)\right] \cdot \vec{n} = 0$

How can I impose the correct boundary condition? Have I misunderstood the documentation, which seems to say that my desired boundary condition is the default?

Comment: I think I have an idea what the issue might be, could you try this `op = Div[Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] + Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}] u[x, y], {x, y}] - Div[Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] u[x, y]` and see if this solves your problem. (I know the equation looks strange),if this is the case, I have an idea what is going on.

Comment: Or alternatively, this equivalent: `op = 2*E^(-x^2 - y^2)*y*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] + 
 2*E^(-x^2 - y^2)*x*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y]`

Comment: Hi user21. When I do that, I get equal fluxes into and out of the box, as desired. But then I'm also solving a different PDE, since your `op` differs from my `op` by a term `- Div[Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] u[x, y]`.

Comment: I *suspect* the natural Neumann b.c. is just what you have observed ( zero gradient, which in this case is *not* zero flux ).  That is to say the result is correct and the issue lies in the docs if they claim natural==zero flux. (My guess they only make that claim in the context of examples w/o the potential term ).

Comment: @george2079, the natural Neumann bc depends on the equation. In this case the equation evaluated to something where the natural bc is $\nabla u \cdot n = 0$. If you do find that claim natural==zero flux in the docs, I'd appreciate if you could let me know.

Comment: My assumption that default (natural) boundary conditions represented zero flux came from reading several parts of the documentation, @user21. For example, the [NeumannValue documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) says that if no bc's are specified, then $\vec{n}\cdot (c \nabla u + \alpha u - \gamma) = 0$ is used. It is not explained how these coefficients are related to the input, but I assumed that the PDE was of the form $\nabla \cdot$current density vector$=0$.

Comment: @user21 That seems consistent with the "Classical Partial Differential Equations" section (see "The Coefficient Form...") of the [FEM documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html), although that suggests that the natural conditions have $+\gamma$ rather than $-\gamma$.

Comment: @GregP, the coefficients in the PDE and the ones addressed through `NeumannValue` are the same - that's why you specify a `Neumann *Value*`. There are actually three sign changes, those appear during integration by parts in the derivation of the FEM.

Comment: @GregP, I wanted to ping you again and ask if it were OK to use some variation of this in the FEM documentation of NDSolve? That would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @user21, sure thing, go ahead and use it!

Comment: @GregP, thanks!

Comment: From this last statement, it seems that one can not use NeumannValue for solving the Poisson equation, i.e. Laplacian u=0 in some 3D volume. Is this true?

Comment: @Secchi, which statement are you referring to? It has been a while since I've looked at all this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is what I think the issue is: Let's look at what `NDSolve` parses.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} ∈ reg, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005}}];
femData = state["FiniteElementData"];
femData["PDECoefficientData"]["All"]

{{{{0}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}}, {{{{{-1, 
      0}, {0, -1}}}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}, {{{{2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x, 
      2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y}}}}, {{4 E^(-x^2 - y^2) - 
     4 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x^2 - 4 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y^2}}}, {{{0}}}, {{{0}}}}
```

So, there is the diffusion term (`{{-1,0},{0,-1}}`) the convection term (`{2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x, 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y}`) and a reaction term. This means `NDSolve` is modeling something like:

∇⃗ ⋅[∇⃗ u(x,y)] + v(x,y)∇⃗ u(x,y) + u(x,y)∇⃗ v(x,y) = 0

If we manually set the PDE coefficients like this, to be a diffusion coefficient and a conservative convection coefficient (with an added minus sign, as noted in the comments)

```
methodData = femData["FEMMethodData"];
bcData = femData["BoundaryConditionData"];
sd = state["SolutionData"][[1]];
vd = methodData["VariableData"];

pdeData = 
 InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
  "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}, 
  "ConservativeConvectionCoefficients" -> {{-{2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x, 
      2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y}}}];
```

This should be more like

∇⃗ ⋅[∇⃗ u(x,y) + u(x,y)∇⃗ v(x,y)]= 0

And discretize and solve the PDE with:

```
dpde = DiscretizePDE[pdeData, methodData, sd];
dbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcData, methodData, sd];
{l, s, d, m} = dpde["SystemMatrices"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s, d, m}, dbcs]
lsol = LinearSolve[s, l];
mesh = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[sd, "Space"]["ElementMesh"];
sol = {u -> ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, lsol]};
```

We see that the difference between the in and out flux is relatively small.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[((Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 5] + 
        u[x, 5] Derivative[0, 1][v][x, 5]) - (Derivative[0, 1][u][
         x, -5] + u[x, -5] Derivative[0, 1][v][x, -5])) /. 
    sol]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Update**

In 10.0.2 a better way to input the PDE and get the expected result is made available:

```
reg = 
  ImplicitRegion[-5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5 && x^2 + y^2 >= 1^2, {x,
     y}];
v = Function[{x, y}, -E^(-x^2 - y^2)];
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == -5], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 5]};
α = Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}];
op = Inactive[Div][
   Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], 
    Inactive[Times][α, u[x, y]]], {x, y}];
solI = NDSolve[{op == 0, bc}, u, {x, y} ∈ reg];
Plot[Evaluate[Function[y,
    (Derivative[0, 1][u][x, y] + 
       u[x, y] Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]) /. 
     solI] /@ {5, -5}], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0}]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time going into the depths of NDSolve. Can you specify where you got `vd`,`sd`,`methodData`, and `bcData`?

Comment: @GregP, sorry my bad. Forgot some of the code. I am not 100% sure this should be considered a bug in `NDSolve`, It has to do with 'premature' evaluation of the PDE. I'll have to think a bit about this. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @GregP, [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Many thanks, @user21. It seems to work quite well, although I did change the sign of `ConservativeConvectionCoefficients` compared to your code. That is, I had `"ConservativeConvectionCoefficients" ->{{{-2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x,-2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y}}}`. This is because the force is minus the gradient of the potential. Alternatively, I suppose I could have set the diffusion tensor to the identity matrix rather than minus the identity matrix.

Comment: As to whether this is a bug or not, I don't think I understand NDSolve deeply enough to know. But I will certainly read the documentation that you linked to.

Comment: @GregP, yes, the sgin change makes sense. I did not think too much about this. Would you mind if I use this example or some variation of it in the documentation. I think it makes for a nice example. I think in essence one would like to specify something like `Inactive[Div[Grad[u[x,y],{x,y}]+Grad[v[x,y],{x,y}]*u[x,y],{x,y}]` but that does not work currently.

Comment: Thanks @user21. I have tried using `Inactive` in various ways without success. And yes, by all means use this example in the documentation if it is useful.

Comment: @GregP, yes not being able to use `Inactive` is a bug and I have fixed that. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GregP, I have updated the solution to show how this is to be specified with 10.0.2. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you misread the documentation for NeumannValue. I found the documentation fairly difficult to fathom. This was mainly my fault because what they do is substantially different than what I expected. I was trying to cram the round peg that is NeumannValue into the square hole that is my brain.

If you can write the PDE as

```
Div J = 0
```

(the form your PDE is in) and you use NeumannValue with its first argument set to zero you are then getting n.J=0. That is if you write your pde as

```
 Div J = NeumannValue[q - r u,pred]
```

where u is the dependent variable you are solving for and 
where pred is true for coordinates that are in the boundaries and false for all other coordinate values then NeumannValue is imposing n.J = q-ru on the boundaries for which pred is true. Thus if you set q =r=0 so that the first argument to NeumannValue is zero then you would in fact be getting the boundary conditions you wanted. If your PDE can't be written as the divergence of a flux (plus time derivatives possibly) or if you want some other boundary conditions then you can't use NeumannValue as far as I know.

Comment: I'm confused. As far as I can tell, your description of the behavior of NDSolve for the PDE $Div J = 0$ and with NeumannValue is exactly what I wanted/hoped for. Given the default NeumannValue[0,pred] behavior when no B.C. is specified, this (desired behavior) would imply no net flux of $J$ out of the box. However, the last plot in my post shows that there is in fact net flux (of $J$). As far as I understand, what you describe above is how I wished NDSolve would work, but didn't seem to.

Comment: The parsing of the PDE was an issue. If you want a more complicated Neumann value to be satisfied then you'd need to describe your PDE with `Inactive`

Comment: If can suggest a little more precisely what you found difficult to fathom, then it might be possible to improve that.