# Accuracy of Grad-Shafranov PDE's NDSolveValue over implicit region

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

### Context

> I need to solve for  the toroidal flux of the magnetic field above an accretion disc.

For this purpose, I define the region over which the flux is non zero,

```
a= 2;
f[R_] = a (1 - R^2)^(1/2 + 1/100);
Ω = ImplicitRegion[z <= f[R], {{R, 0, 1}, {z, 0, f[0]}}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I solve for the  force-free [`Grad-Shafranov equation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grad%E2%80%93Shafranov_equation):

```
eqn0 =R D[P[R, z], {R, 2}] + R D[P[R, z], {z, 2}] - D[P[R, z], R] == -R/2;
```

as follows

```
P0 = NDSolveValue[{eqn0, DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, R == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, z == f[R]]},  P, {R, z} ∈ Ω];
```

I then plot the resulting (normalized) flux map:

```
np = NMaximize[P0[R, z], {R, z} ∈ Ω][[1]];
ContourPlot[ P0[R, z]/np, {R, z} ∈ Ω,PlotPoints -> 50, 
ImageSize -> Small, AspectRatio -> Sqrt[f[0]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and look at the value of the flux on the boundary

```
Plot[P0[R, z]/np /. z -> f[R], {R, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it seems to satisfy  the boundary condition.

If I now look at the pressure above the cap:

```
grad2 = Grad[P0[R, z]/np, {R, z}] // (#.#/R^2 &);
Plot[grad2 /. z -> f[R], {R, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is not   smooth enough…

**On top of that**

If I decide to extend the height of the column over which the flux 
is defined, to say

```
 a=15;
```

Then the accuracy of he map deteriorates considerably for the map

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and even more for the pressure:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### QUESTION(S)

> How can improve the accuracy of the solution found by [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolveValue.html)?

I understand that there are options such as `PrecisionGoal` or `Method`, but I guess I am trying to ask a more general question:

> More generally, what is the best **learning** strategy within mathematica to be able to find such improvement? (a.k.a how not to get lost in the documentation?). The idea being, next time I can figure this myself :-)

Mathematica gives the following warning, which is undoubtedly a hint

`NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help`.

but I do not know how to follow it up.

**PS:** If, instead of

```
 f[R_] = a (1 - R^2)^(1/2 + 1/100);
```

I have

```
f[R_] = a (1 - R^2)^(1/2);
```

the integrator  also fails miserably, which is rather odd.

Comment: related: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1446/7683

Comment: and also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58455/1089

Answer (score 2):

### This is not a full answer but what I found so far…

Following @user21's [`link`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html)

If I use

```
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}, 
"IntegrationOrder" -> 3}}
```

as in

```
P0 = NDSolveValue[{eqn0, DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, R == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, z == f[R]]}, 
   P, {R, z} ∈ Ω
   , Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}, 
       "IntegrationOrder" -> 3}}];
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is clearly better.

It still fails to get a very accurate pressure for `a=15` though.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> One should not consider this an answer because it falls short in defining a strategy to identify what the proper options should be. Here I am just fishing randomly.

Comment: I can not look at this right away, but have a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) desciption of convection dominated PDEs.

Comment: @user21 thanks. Seems quite relevant indeed.