# How to specify PDE Boundary condition on a B-spline?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, splines, electromagnetics

### Context

> I would like to solve a PDE on a boundary which is parametrized as a [BSpline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).
> I am trying to solve the  force-free [`Grad-Shafranov equation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grad%E2%80%93Shafranov_equation) on a boundary whose shape I do not know in advance.

Specifically I need to solve for the toroidal flux of the magnetic field above an accretion disc.

---

The Grad-Shafranov equation reads (in cylindrical coordinates)

```
R D[P[R, z], {R, 2}] + R D[P[R, z], {z, 2}] - D[P[R, z], R] == - R/2;
```

and I am seeking solution satisfying `P==0` on a spline, see below.

This question is related to the physical context of that [`question`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88676/1089),
where we try in to explain astrophysical jets like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Eventually I would like to optimize the problem while changing the
shape of the spline.

---

### First attempt

I define my region via a BSpline:

```
ff0 = BSplineFunction[pts = {{1, 0}, {1.2, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

So the upper envelope of the jet looks like this:

```
pl0 = ParametricPlot[ ff0[t] // Release, {t, 0, 1},
  Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 15, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the region like that:

```
pl = ParametricPlot[r ff0[t] // Release, {t, 0, 1}, {r, 0.01, 1},
  Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 15, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can then discretize both the boundary and the region:

```
Ω = DiscretizeGraphics[pl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
δΩ = DiscretizeGraphics[pl0, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and then solve for the PDE

```
eqn0 = R D[P[R, z], {R, 2}] +  R D[P[R, z], {z, 2}] - D[P[R, z], R] == - R/2;
P0 = NDSolveValue[{eqn0, 
   DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, R == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, {R, z} ∈ δΩ],
   DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == E  R^2 Log[1/R^2], z == 0]}, 
    P, {R, z} ∈ Ω, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10000}, 
      "IntegrationOrder" -> 3}}]
```

If I then try and plot the resulting PDE solution, `P0`,

```
ContourPlot[P0[R, z], {R, z} ∈ Ω, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap", ImageSize -> Small, 
 PlotRange -> All,
 FrameLabel -> {R, z},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even though it seems happy, it satisfies very poorly the boundary on
the spine:

```
Plot[ P0 @@ ff0[t], {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This should be zero…

---

### Second attempt

Following J. M., I have attempted using explicit splines  and [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricRegion.html)
as follows:

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {1.8, 3}, {0, 2}};
 {xu, yu} = Transpose[pts]; 
n = 2;m = Length[pts]; 
knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
         ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten; 
fx[t_] = xu.Table[ BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}]; 
fy[t_] = yu.Table[ BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
```

Indeed

```
ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

seems to return the same spine; now I can define my region and triangulate it:

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{{r fx[t], r fy[t]}, 1 <= t <= 1 && 0 <= r <= 1}, {t, r}];
 Ω = DiscretizeRegion[pr, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
 RegionPlot[Ω]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and similarly its boundary:

```
  dpr = ParametricRegion[{{ fx[t], fy[t]}, 0 <= t <= 1}, t];
  δΩ = DiscretizeRegion[dpr, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
```

But applying the same PDE on these regions/boundary with these newly regions yields the same inaccuracies as before (boundary condition not
satisfied properly on δΩ).

**The problem might be** with the second discretize region:  indeed

```
   Show[δΩ, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

presents some defect in the triangulation.
Note in particular the two points at the origin and at coordinate `(0.9,-0.2)`.

---

### Questions

> Any suggestion on why it fails to satisfy the boundary?
>
> Any suggestion on how to avoid going through [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) ?
>
> Any suggestion on how to specify [`DirichletCondition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DirichletCondition.html)
> on [`BSplineFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineFunction.html)?

I feel I am not using the most straightforward method here but…

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [decomposing your `BSplineFunction[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24462) and forming the corresponding `ParametricRegion[]`?

Comment: no because i did not know about parametric region. Thanks

Comment: @user21 would you please be able to throw some suggestions? It seems it is a problem of general interest from the point of view of solving large classes of PDEs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way (as pointed out by J. M.) is to convert splines into implicit functions. The real issue you are having is that you'd need a second order mesh to get a decent solution. Note that `DiscretizeGraphics` and `DiscretizeRegion` create first order meshes. So you'd need to use `ToElementMesh`. We also would like to have a finer boundary resolution, thus use "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure". Another thing to think about is the way the boundary condition is specified on the spline. A better way to specify is to say "all boundary elements where `R` and `z` are not 0 instead of the code to rest for region member ship on the boundary with `Element`.

This then gives:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
pts = {{1, 0}, {1.8, 3}, {0, 2}};
{xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
n = 2; m = Length[pts];
knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
    ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten;
fx[t_] = xu.Table[
    BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
fy[t_] = yu.Table[
    BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
pr = ParametricRegion[{{r fx[t], r fy[t]}, -1 <= t <= 1 && 
     0 <= r <= 1}, {t, r}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[pr, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Note that the mesh order is 2.

```
mesh["MeshOrder"]
2
```

From there we go to:

```
eqn0 = R D[P[R, z], {R, 2}] + R D[P[R, z], {z, 2}] - 
    D[P[R, z], R] == -R/2;
P0 = NDSolveValue[{eqn0,
    DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, R == 0],
    DirichletCondition[P[R, z] == 0, R != 0 && z != 0], 
    DirichletCondition[
     P[R, z] == E R^2 Log[1/(R + $MachineEpsilon)^2], z == 0]
    }, P, {R, z} \[Element] mesh];
```

Note the `$MachineEpsilon` to avoid division by zero.

```
ContourPlot[P0[R, z], {R, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap", PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {R, z}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

And then this is about 2 order of magnitude better:

```
ff0 = BSplineFunction[pts];
Plot[P0 @@ ff0[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Which I hope is reasonable.

Note, that the boundary conditions are set to zero in the interpolating function:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
bc = bmesh["Coordinates"];
nodes = DeleteCases[bc, {x_ /; x < 10^-3, y_} | {x_, y_ /; y < 10^-3}];
MinMax[P0 @@@ nodes]
{-1.3877787807814457`*^-17, 2.7755575615628914`*^-17}
```

So what you see above is a an interpolation "limitiation" (it's "only" second order accurate). What I am not sure about is why it does not deteriorate further if the boundary is refined. Nevertheless, I think, it's OK to take the derivative of the interpolating function since doing that (currently V10.2) does not evaluates points that are not on the mesh.

Comment: …so that was the secret sauce! :)

Comment: @user21 thanks so much! What could I tweak to improve the accuracy of P0 being zero on the boundary? I am asking because what I really need is the derivative of P0 on the boundary, so P0 has to be very accurately zero there. I tried changing MaxBoundaryCellMeasure but it seems to have no effect in fact.

Comment: @chris, added some more info. I am not sure how to get a better interpolation, but the solution on the mesh is accurate.

Comment: @chris, if there is no objections, I'd like to use this as a basis for a [FEM Best Practice](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) to show the use of splines in the boundary.

Comment: @user21 sure: I am honored :-)

Comment: @user21 The mesh seems to fail relatively systematically, e.g. for  `{{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 3}}`.  Would you have a workaround? I have updated this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89166/1089 with the pb.

Comment: @user21 I found a workaround: this works: Jet0[{{1, 0}, {18, 18}/10, {0, 2.2}}] !

Comment: @chris, yes try to `Rationalize` all numbers, that may help. Sometimes you can find a solution with more symbolic processing time e.g.: `SetSystemOptions[
 "FiniteElementOptions" -> {"SymbolicProcessing" -> 10.}]`

Comment: @user21 , nice work!