# Poor/wrong sampling in 1D DiscretizeRegion of splines?

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, mesh

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 11.3**

---

### Context

In relation to this [`question`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88874/1089.html)
I have would like to use  splines to define a [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricRegion.html)
and [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html)

I proceed as follows:

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {1.8, 3}, {0, 2}};
 {xu, yu} = Transpose[pts]; 
n = 2;m = Length[pts]; 
knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
         ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten; 
fx[t_] = xu.Table[ BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}]; 
fy[t_] = yu.Table[ BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
```

So that

```
ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I would like to Discretize this BSpline as follows:

```
  dpr = ParametricRegion[{{ fx[t], fy[t]}, 0 <= t <= 1}, t];
  δΩ = DiscretizeRegion[dpr, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
```

This seems to produce a buggy region. Indeed

```
   Show[δΩ, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

presents some defect in the triangulation.
Note in particular the two points at the origin and at coordinate `(0.9,-0.2)`.

---

### Question

> Is this a bug in DiscretizeRegion?
>
> Can anyone reproduce this problem?

I am using *mathematica* 10.1 on macos X.

Thanks!

### Update

In mathematica 10.2 is works better but not always.
For instance let us define

```
 << NDSolve`FEM`

Jet0[pts_: {{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 2}}] := 
 Module[{xu, yu, n, m, knots, fx, fy, pr, mesh, t, r},
  {xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
  n = 2; m = Length[pts];
  knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
     ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten;
  fx[t_] = 
   xu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  fy[t_] = 
   yu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  pr = ParametricRegion[{{r fx[t], r fy[t]}, 0 <= t <= 1 && 
      0 <= r <= 1}, {t, r}];
  mesh = ToElementMesh[pr, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.1];
  mesh["Wireframe"]]
```

so that

```
Jet0[]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but on the other hand

```
Jet0[{{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 3}}]
```

produces

$Failed[Wireframe]

Comment: I can reproduce this on **Windows** in **10.1** but it has been fixed in **10.2**.

Comment: @RunnyKine thanks! Do you think it is the source of my problem in the linked question? Should I retag my question as bug? as 10.1?

Comment: I don't think that's the source of the problem. If you can rewrite the `ParametricRegion` as an `ImplicitRegion` you may have better chances. For some reason, *Mathematica* doesn't know how to handle `ParametricRegion` properly.

Comment: @RunnyKine would you know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: "convert to `ImplicitRegion[]`" - should be doable via `PiecewiseExpand[]` and a few other functions, but since it's piecewise polynomial, you will have to tack on not a few inequalities to restrict the domain. Just describing the route makes me shudder…

Comment: Refs for tagging bugs: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1611, http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[pr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}]` works in V10.2. -- This also works, `ToElementMesh[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[pr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}]]` and gives a warning that might be significant.

Comment: @MichaelE2 please write this as an answer?

Comment: Including the word "fixed" on the first line [is going to make this post disappear from the bug-radar](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Comment: @Szabolcs what do you suggest? Its a bug with an easy workaround?

Comment: I think there's an error in `Jet0`: Should it read `0 <= t <= 1` instead of `-1 <= t <= 1` in `ParametricRegion`?  (Doesn't fix problem, though, it seems.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes you are right. I had corrected it but not online :-)

Comment: @Michael, `BSplineBasis[]` zeroes out outside $[0,1]$, but it's better that you corrected @chris. ;)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes, and I was hoping that was the source of the problem, but alas....

Comment: This seems fixed in V11.3. Can you confirm that Chris? Thanks.

Comment: @user21 Indeed: should I modify the header to say so?

Comment: That would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DiscretizeRegion` will work in place of `ToElementMesh`:

```
Jet0[pts_: {{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 2}}] := 
 Module[{xu, yu, n, m, knots, fx, fy, pr, t, r},
  {xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
  n = 2; m = Length[pts];
  knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
     ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten;
  fx[t_] = xu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  fy[t_] = yu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  pr = ParametricRegion[{{r fx[t], r fy[t]}, 0 <= t <= 1 && 0 <= r <= 1},
        {t, r}];
  DiscretizeRegion[pr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}]]

Jet0[{{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: your answer is useful for people who are happy with `DiscretizeRegion`. According to @user21 I need `ToElementMesh` in order to be able to solve a PDE on it.

Comment: @chris `ToElementMesh@Jet0[{{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 3}}]` generally converts a MeshRegion to an ElementMesh with no problem.  `NDSolve` should convert a MeshRegion automatically, too, but often one wants to set up the ElementMesh first before calling `NDSolve`.  (The problem here is getting from a parametric description to any sort of mesh.)

Comment: @chris, Ayy, I forgot there is a difference: Along the boundary, the quadratic vertices in converting a MeshRegion are placed on the **linear** boundary elements; in converting a Region, they are placed on the Region's boundary and thus are more accurate for solving PDEs.

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes this is quite an important point, For numerics `ToElementMesh` is preferable.

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround involving `Rationalize`.

```
Jet0[pts0_: {{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 2}}] := 
 Module[{xu, yu, n, m, knots, fx, fy, pr, mesh, t, r},
   pts=Rationalize[pts0,0.001];
  {xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
  n = 2; m = Length[pts];
  knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), 
     ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten;
  fx[t_] = 
   xu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  fy[t_] = 
   yu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
  pr = ParametricRegion[{{r fx[t], r fy[t]}, -1 <= t <= 1 && 
      0 <= r <= 1}, {t, r}];
  mesh = ToElementMesh[pr, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.1];
  mesh["Wireframe"]]
```

works as expected:

```
 Jet0[{{1, 0}, {1.8, 1.8}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I thought the error with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` suggested a numerical issue. +1