# ElementMeshContourPlot and PlotLegend

Tags: graphics, legending, mesh

Does anybody know why ElementMeshContourPlot ignored PlotLegends->Automatic? I have used the useful topic about Von Mises stress but I vould like a colored scale on the right of the plot. With CountourPlot it works! Thank!

Comment: `ElementMeshContourPlot` is not a built-in function. Where did you get this from?

Comment: [`PlotLegends` is not an option of `ElementMeshContourPlot`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rH2v6.png)

Comment: I get ElementMeshContourPlot  from Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]  you can see my problem in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102522/stress-calculations-using-finite-elements . I red that ElementMeshContourPlot  has the same option of ContourPlot

Comment: There is quite a bit of overlap, but their options are not completely identical. Run this to find the unique options: `<|#1 -> Complement[Options[#1][[All, 1]], Options[#2][[All, 1]]], #2 ->
     Complement[Options[#2][[All, 1]], 
     Options[#1][[All, 1]]]|> &[ContourPlot, ElementMeshContourPlot]`

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right and your suggestion clarify. THis is the output:

Comment: <|ContourPlot -> {Evaluated, EvaluationMonitor, Exclusions, 
   ExclusionsStyle, MaxRecursion, PlotLegends, PlotPoints, PlotTheme, 
   ScalingFunctions, TargetUnits, WorkingPrecision}, 
 ElementMeshContourPlot -> {DataRange, InterpolationOrder, 
   MaxPlotPoints}|>

Comment: So  I do not remember where I red they have the same options but they haven't so ok